# variable at end of string

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm trying to open a popup window on the left upper corner of the current window. So far the y positioning works fine, but I can't get the x to work. how do i get the syntax right?

```
function openPopup() {
 var url = this.href;
 window.open(url, 'popup_id', 'scrollbars, resizable, width=400, height=300, top='+ window.screenY,'left='+ window.screenX'');
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you see syntax errors on the console? If so, will you post them?

Comment: `top='+ window.screenY,'left='+ window.screenX` should be `top='+ window.screenY+',left='+ window.screenX`.  Note the extra `+`, and how the `,` is inside the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the second `+`

```
window.open(url, 'popup_id', 'scrollbars, resizable, width=400, height=300, top='+ window.screenY +', left='+ window.screenX);
```

Comment: Why should a comma be appended to this string?

Comment: copy past mistake, thanks for pointing out. tymeJV's solution works (if ,' is removed)

Comment: @tymeJV: The above is invalid, correct your code. EDIT: I've done it for you